# How does this print a reversed linked list

Tags: python, list, linked-list

How does this piece of code print a linked list reversed?  I'm pretty curious how the new list comes to this way.

```
class Empty:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.IsEmpty = True
Empty = Empty()

class Node:
    def __init__ (self,value,tail):
        self.IsEmpty = False
        self.value = value
        self.tail = tail

l = Node(1,Node(2,Node(3,Node(4,Empty))))   


c = l
nl = Empty

while not l.IsEmpty:
    nl = Node(l.value,nl)
    l = l.tail

while not nl.IsEmpty:
    print(nl.value)
    nl = nl.tail
```

Comment: hey it's zero-vote zone here. Consider at least accepting one of the 534 answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It builds a forwards list

```
l = Node(1,Node(2,Node(3,Node(4,Empty))))
```

Then builds a backwards list from that forwards list

```
nl = Empty

while not l.IsEmpty:
    nl = Node(l.value,nl)
    l = l.tail
```

Then prints that list out in order, which is the reverse of the first list.

This is a pretty convoluted way of doing things.  Better would be something recursive, like:

```
def printer(curr):
    if curr.isEmpty:
        return
    printer(curr.tail)
    print(curr.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't *print* reversed, `nl` is *built* reversed:

```
while not l.IsEmpty:
    nl = Node(l.value,nl)
    l = l.tail
```

each new `nl` is the tail of the next one. So 1 is the tail for 2, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what is happening in the first `while` loop. It builds a new list in reverse. We start with `Empty`. Then each iteration:

```
new_list = Node(l.current_value, Node(l.previous_value))
```

Where `previous_value` is the value encountered first while iterating through the original list. So, this could be expanded to:

```
Node(l.last_value, Node(l.second_to_last, Node(...Node(l.first_value, Empty)...)))
```